# How can i consistently align label font text next to the input form to be exactly centered vertically in CSS?

Tags: html, css, input, label, alignment

I have a label and an input form next to it. By default, with font family Cambria, the input box is slightly lower than the label text to it.
[this is what's my current setup looks like, if you look closely, input box is slightly lower than the font](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Zy7I.png)

[this is what i am trying to achieve: input box exactly centered after ":" (colon)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/heq5F.png) 
I was able to achieve it through manipulating height/line-height of label in CSS, but i am trying to find a more elegant and simple approach (if its possible) to adjust any font next to desired item.

https://jsfiddle.net/5yuv34Ln/1/ - this is my original code where you can see that input form is slightly lower than font.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/styles.css">
    <title>Guess a Number Game</title>
</head>

<body>
    <main>
        <header class="header">Guess a Number Game</header>
        <div class="main-text">From 1 to 20</div>
        <div class="input">
            <label class="main-text" for="guess-input">Put your guess here:</label>
            <input id="guess-input" type="number">
        </div>
        <section>
            <div id="feedback"></div>
        </section>
        <div>
            <button id="guess-button" class="btn">Guess</button>
        </div>
        <div>
            <button id="again-button" class="btn">Play Again</button>
        </div>
    </main>
    <script src="scripts/index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS

```
.btn {
    font-family: Cambria, Cochin, Georgia, Times, 'Times New Roman', serif;
    font-size: x-large;
    margin: 10px 0px;
}

.main-text {
    font-family: Cambria, Cochin, Georgia, Times, 'Times New Roman', serif;
    font-size: x-large;

}

.header {
    font-family: Cambria, Cochin, Georgia, Times, 'Times New Roman', serif;
    font-size: x-large;
    border-bottom: solid;
    background-color: beige;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: darkslategray
}

#feedback {
    font-family: Cambria, Cochin, Georgia, Times, 'Times New Roman', serif;
    font-size: x-large;
    border-top: solid;
    margin-top: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
}

#guess-input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
#guess-input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    margin: 0;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5yuv34Ln/ - this is solution that my friend offered, but i am wondering if there is any other options i can use to do so in a simple or organized way, without manually adjusting pixels around label.

Comment: I think you may mean “vertically” in the title.

Comment: Yes, i am sorry for the confusion. You're correct!

Comment: This may be a case of 'be careful what you wish for'. Characters that the user types into the input box as it stands currently will be aligned with the label text (same baseline). If you move one or the other this will no longer be the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in order to align vertically the two elements in the line you just have to specify a line height for the row items and change the *vertical-align* value for the parent DIV (that is "*baseline*") to "*text-top*" like this :

```
div.input input,
div.input label{
  line-height: 30px;
  vertical-align: text-top;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I guess what it does is giving both items enough height for its content and aligning on top of it. But what if i want my font and input box to remain same size and just aligning text to input box centrally? Sorry for additional questions.

Comment: On your second screenshot the input height was slightly higher than on the first, but If you don't want to change the line-height, you can put the input and label to vertical-alin:text-bottom, it shoud do the trick :


div.input input,
div.input label{
  vertical-align: text-bottom;
}